# Function performs as expected, but returns a nil value at the end of the loop

Tags: algorithm, search, lua

The function performs as expected, up until the point where I try to have it return a table with 2 entries. Instead, it returns nil.

I'm working in ZeroBrane Studio using what I assume is the most up to date Lua version.

```
function round(n)
  local up = math.ceil(n)
  if up - (n + 0.5) <= 0 then return math.ceil(n) 
  else return math.floor(n) end
end
function neighbors(t, x)
  local mid = round(#t/2)
  local tt = {}
    if #t == 2 then 
      print("Finished Search; returning {"..t[1]..", "..t[2].."}.") 
      return t
    end
    if x >= t[mid] then
      for i = mid, #t do
        table.insert(tt, t[i])
      end
    elseif x < t[mid] then
      for i = 1, mid do
        table.insert(tt, t[i])
      end
    end
  print(table.concat(tt, ", "))
  neighbors(tt, x)
end
test = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24}

nn = neighbors(test, 14.25)
print(nn)
```

I expect the debug output to be "table: 0x000291f8" or something of the sort, but instead I get nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `return` at the end of your `neighbors` function. it should be:

```
  return neighbors(tt, x)
```

Your error is that the return of `t` on line 11 of the program will not return the value all the way back up the chain of your recursive calls, it only returns it to the last function who call `neighbors`.

Adding the `return neighbors(tt, x)` will cause the call that actually gets `t` to return taht value up the chain all the way to the first call of `neighbors`

---

here is a simple example of a common recursive program:

```
function factorial(n)
    if (n == 0) then
        return 1
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1) --note we return this line not just call it.
    end
end
```